# 'gulp-babel' not working in node js version 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

I am getting error, when require `gulp-babel` in my gulp file, to use `es6` syntax in my js files.

```
/home/logakrishnan/Documents/project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:77
  constructor(options, {
                       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/logakrishnan/Documents/project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:153:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

Node version: `v4.4.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to upgrade your Node.js version. (Node 4 is from 2016, a relative eternity in JavaScript terms.)

[At the time of writing, Babel requires Node 6.9 or newer.](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/e6264a09921c60b8f18870d0a75678e4fa04f0f8/package.json#L79)

Comment: is there any alternate solutions, other than upgrading node version?

Comment: Using an older Babel, but that might be tough.